# Which brush to use for creating art like in the videogame "Braid"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, games

I'm really impressed with the artwork in Braid so I'd like to learn how to do similar stuff in Photoshop.

I have tried around with the brushes but haven't quite figured out how to get the same strokes.

Which brushes are suitable and where can I find them?

Here are some examples of the artwork:

[Braid Title Screen](http://www.davidhellman.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/aob07-13.jpg)

[Braid Title Screen 2](http://www.davidhellman.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/aob07-16.jpg)

[Tim's House](http://www.davidhellman.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/aob08-17.jpg)

[World](http://download.gameblog.fr/images/blogs/7428/100975.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this can be created with one brush but more likely with many different ones and a lot of trial and error. David Hellman talks about the design-process here: http://www.davidhellman.net/blog/the-art-of-braid-index

Comment: Yeah I have seen the posts on the design process, that's where I got most of those example images from. I realize it's not only one single brush, but there must be a set of brushes that are suitable for this kind of artwork.

Comment: I am sure many are. It depends on the artist. I suggest you find/create some, try them out and see what works for you. It depends heavy on your personal style. If you don't know where to find brushes, try googling for photoshop brushes, look at deviantart and similar platforms that offer exchange of resources like that.